# How can I make it so when the button is pressed the tk window closes?

Tags: python, sql, user-interface, tkinter

I have a program which when a button is pressed on the GUI a SQL database launches the window is called 'change' and when the button view table is pressed my SQL query launches. I have tried to use the root.destroy() function but it just seems to lag out my computer and the tk window doesn't close. here is the GUI that links to the SQL query:

```
import tkinter as tk
def change():
    frame.destroy()
    HEIGHT = 700
    WIDTH = 800

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()
    #Renamed the second frame
    framee = tk.Frame(root, bg = '#8BDFF4')
    framee.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.5)
    button3 = button3 =tk.Button(framee, text = "outflows", bg = '#8BF4AB', fg = 'black', activebackground = '#62AF7A', command = viewout)
    button3.place(rely = 0.35, relx = 0.3975, relwidth = 0.25, relheight = 0.25)
```

and here is the query which is lagging out the tk window when the destroy function runs and doesn't actually destroy the window:

```
import sqlite3
def viewout():
    frame.destroy(change)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('NEA.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM outflows1")
    data = c.fetchall()
    print(data)
```

so the desired output is when the button is pressed on the GUI the tk window stops running and the query runs so far the query is running however the tk window just lags out until I kill it.

Comment: how bout just `frame.close()` ? I dont work with tk much so :/

Comment: @JoranBeasley: frames don't have a `close` method.

Comment: `change.destroy()` ?

Comment: when code runs your query then GUI (not only tkinter but also `PyQt`, `wxPython`, etc.) is waiting for end of this function and it redraws/updates window after end of your function (when it returns to `mainloop`) - this way GUI can redraw all widgets in one moment and it doesn't flick. If you want to redraw at once then it may need `frame.refresh()` to force `mainloop` to redraw it at this moment.

Comment: @furas I have added frame.refresh() in to the end of the query and it makes no difference in the output. I have also tried putting it outside of the query and the problem still persists

Comment: you have to add `refresh()` after `destroy()`, before query. But if this still doesn't work then you will have to show minimal working code which we could simply copy and run - to see problem.

Comment: what is `change` in `destry(change)`? You have function `def change()` but `destroy` needs `widget`, not `function`. Did you run code in console/terminal to see error message? `frame.destroy(change)` is not correct code and it should give error message.

Comment: @furas this is the error it gives ```TypeError: BaseWidget.destroy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: as I said - `frame.destroy(change)` is wrong. `destroy()` doesn't get any arguments. It has to be `change.destroy()`  if `change` is a widget - but it seems `change` is a function - so maybe it should be `framee.destroy()` (with double `e`) but it would need also `global framee`